# silverlight adding single prism command delegate to a list of items in xaml

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

I'm building a menu using Prism (using a trtelerik tree view with hierarchy data templates but hopefully the details don't matter) and I'm trying to set up a Click.Command on each menu items bindings that will all call the same delegate command which is defined in the view model. The menu is built up out of items which I don't really want to put any references to the command in.

How do I bind the command to each of these items in xaml? I've looked around and it looks like in WPF I could use a relative source binding and find ancestors but there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this in silverlight. Can I setup the delegate as a static resource somehow? I don't think I can create a static resource to the view model as this uses Unity to resolve paramters to it's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to bind to the UserControl's DataContext (or any other control's DataContext) via ElementName binding.

```
<UserControl x:Name="Control" xmlns:Cal="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation"...

Cal:Click.Command="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=DataContext.SomeVMCommand}"
```

[Here's a similar post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051388/wpf-mvvm-command-binding-inside-of-an-itemscontrol)